# Sql Server Update taking forever

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table containing less than 1000 records. Each record contains an ID that is indexed, an integer user variable, and 4 varbinary(max) columns that can each be null, or filled with up to 5mb of data.

the following select returns in less than a second

```
SELECT ID, UserVar, Data1, Data2, Data3, Data4 FROM MyTable WHERE ID = 1
```

the following update runs indefinitely

```
UPDATE MyTable SET UserVar = 1 WHERE ID = 1
```

I have no foreign keys, no triggers, and no other process uses this table. Is there anything I can do to troubleshoot this issue?

:EDIT:

sp_who and sp_who2 both return a single record for the update I am running, and nothing else

select @@TRANCOUNT returns 0

:EDIT2:

Turns out I had a zombie datareader open from a previous failed debug attempt. I'm not sure why this didn't show up under sp_who or @@TRANCOUNT.

Comment: There is some lock on the table or record. You should use sp_who or sp_who2 while that query is running to see what it is waiting on. The `select` returns fast because it does not need an exclusive lock to read the record, the update does.

Comment: sp_who and sp_who2 both return a single record for the update I am running, and nothing else

Comment: I agree with Igor.  There may be an open transaction as well???

Comment: select @@TRANCOUNT returns 0

Comment: Try running ROLLBACK TRAN a couple of times to see if there are any transactions currently open.

Comment: Look at your estimated execution plan

Answer (score 0):

sp_WhoIsActive was meant for that.

https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2010/09/sql-server-dba-scripts-how-to-find-slow-sql-server-queries/